Find $\sum_{n_1+2n_2+\cdots +rn_r=n\\n_1,n_2,...,n_r\ge 0}\frac{1}{n_1!n_2!\cdots n_r!1^{n_1}2^{n_2}\cdots r^{n_r}}$
This is problem 9.101 from A path to combinatorics for undergraduates.
Let $n$ and $r$ be positive integers. Prove that $$\sum_{n_1+2n_2+\cdots +rn_r=n\\n_1,n_2,...,n_r\ge 0}\frac{1}{n_1!n_2!\cdots n_r!1^{n_1}2^{n_2}\cdots r^{n_r}}=1$$
I figured it may have something to do with multinomial coefficient, but since it's not $n_1+n_2+\cdots +n_r=n$, I can't directly change each term on the sum to a multinomial coefficient divided by a product of integers.
This identity was called Cauchy's identity in the book. However, I can't seem to find any other sources that has that identity on the Internet.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.
Edit: The expression is incorrect. I guess the problem is finding a closed form for $\sum_{n_1+2n_2+\cdots +rn_r=n\\n_1,n_2,...,n_r\ge 0}\frac{1}{n_1!n_2!\cdots n_r!1^{n_1}2^{n_2}\cdots r^{n_r}}$ rather than proving the identity.

For $r=1$, the sum has only one term, which is $\frac{1}{n!}$, and thus it isn't equal to $1$ for $n\geq 2$. Are you sure this is the right expression?

@imtrying46 That expression is exactly what is written in the book.

1. Setting
For each permutation $\sigma$ of the set $[n] = \{1, \ldots, n\}$, let $m_k(\sigma)$ denote the number of $k$-cycles in $\sigma$. Also, let $\mathfrak{G}_n$ denote the set of all permutations on $[n]$.
Now for each of $n_{[1:n]} = (n_1, \ldots, n_n)$ satisfying $\sum_k k n_k = n$ and $n_k \geq 0$ for all $k$, we say that $\sigma$ belongs to the conjugacy class $n_{[1:n]}$ if $m_{[1:n]}(\sigma) = n_{[1:n]}$ holds.
Under this setting, we prove the following equivalent identity
$$ n! = \sum_{\text{all valid $n_{[1:n]}$'s}}  \frac{n!}{\prod_{k=1}^{n} n_k! k^{n_k} } \tag{1} $$
by counting the number of permutations belonging to a given conjugacy class.
2. Proof
To prove the claim, we fix a permutation $\tau$ in the conjugacy class $n_{[1:n]}$. Then all the other permutations in the same conjugacy class can be obtained from $\tau$ by conjugation $\tau \mapsto \eta\tau\eta^{-1}$ for some permutation $\eta$, i.e., re-labeling of the elements of $[n]$ by $\eta$. Moreover, for each permutation $\rho$ belonging to the same conjugacy class (i.e., $m_{[1:n]}(\rho) = n_{[1:n]}$), there are precisely
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{n} n_k! k^{n_k} $$
conjugations $\square \mapsto \eta\square\eta^{-1}$ that transforms $\tau$ to $\rho$. Indeed,

there are $n_k!$ ways to pair $k$-cycles between $\tau$ and $\rho$, and
for each of such pairs, there are $k$ ways to permute the selected $k$-cycle of $\tau$ to obtain the selected $k$-cycle of $\rho$.

Therefore, the number of elements in the conjugacy class $n_{[1:n]}$ is precisely
$$ \frac{n!}{\prod_{k=1}^{n} n_k! k^{n_k} }, $$
and summing this for all possible choices of $n_{[1:n]}$ yields the desired identity $\text{(1)}$.

3. Discussion on the Truncated Sum
For the truncated sum,
$$ S_{n,r} := \sum_{\text{all valid $n_{[1:r]}$'s}} \prod_{k=1}^{r} \frac{1}{n_k! k^{n_k} }, $$
for $r < n$, I have no idea whether it admits a nice closed form, letting alone how to find such one. Instead, let me describe the generating function of $S_{n,r}$.
1st Representation. Let $g(x)$ be defined by
$$ g(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{r} \frac{x^k}{k}. $$
This function has the property that $g^{(k)}(0) = (k-1)! \cdot \mathbf{1}[1 \leq k \leq r]$. Then by the Faà di Bruno's formula,
\begin{align*}
S_{n,r}
&= \sum_{\text{all valid $n_{[1:n]}$'s}} \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)^{n_k}}{n_k! k^{n_k} } \\
&= [x^n] \exp(g(x))
= [x^n] \exp\biggl( \sum_{k=1}^{r} \frac{x^k}{k} \biggr).
\end{align*}
As a sanity check, note that if $r \geq n$, then
$$ S_{n,r}
= [x^n] \exp\biggl( \sum_{k=1}^{r} \frac{x^k}{k} \biggr)
= [x^n] \exp\biggl( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k} \biggr)
= [x^n] \frac{1}{1-x}
= 1. $$
2nd Representation. As @Mike Earnest pointed out in his comment, we can give a probabilistic interpretation of $S_{n,r}$. Indeed, we begin with the following identity:

Theorem. Let $\sigma$ be a random permutation sampled uniformly at random from $\mathfrak{G}_n$. Then for any variables $x_1, \ldots, x_n$,
$$\mathbf{E}\biggl[ \prod_{k=1}^{n} x_k^{m_k(\sigma)} \biggr]
= \sum_{\text{all valid $n_{[1:n]}$'s}} \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{x_k^{n_k}}{n_k! k^{n_k}}, $$
with the understanding that $0^0 = 1$.

This is easily proved by modifying the above proof. Now we plug $x_1 = \ldots = x_r = 1$ and $x_{r+1} = \ldots = x_n = 0$ into the above identity. Then by noting that
$$ \left( \prod_{k=1}^{r} 1^{n_k} \right) \left( \prod_{k=r+1}^{n} 0^{n_k} \right)
= \mathbf{1}[n_k = 0, \ \forall k > r] $$
we obtain following probabilistic interpretation of $S_{n,r}$:
$$ \mathbf{P}(\text{$\sigma$ has no cycles with length $> r$}) = S_{n,r}. $$

The dark art of finding the right objects to count never fails to impress me (+1).

Do you agree that $S_{n,r}$ is equal to the probability that the cycle lengths of a randomly chosen permutation on $n$ elements are all at most $r$?

@MikeEarnest, That's a nice interpretation! I can see that too.

This is the cycle index of the symmetric group evaluated at $a_\ell=1$. We have
$$Z(S_n) = [u^n] \exp
\left(\sum_{\ell \ge 1}
a_\ell \frac{u^\ell}{\ell}\right).$$
Doing the substitution yields
$$[u^n] \exp
\left(\sum_{\ell \ge 1}
\frac{u^\ell}{\ell}\right)
= [u^n] \exp\log\frac{1}{1-u}
= [u^n] \frac{1}{1-u} = 1.$$

Consider the generating function $$F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty 
\tiny\left(\sum_{n_1+2n_2+\cdots +rn_r=n\\n_1,n_2,...,n_r\ge 0}\frac{1}{n_1!n_2!\cdots n_r!1^{n_1}2^{n_2}\cdots r^{n_r}}\right)\large x^n$$
Then,
$$F(x)=\left(\sum_{n_1=0}^\infty\frac1{n_1!}(\tfrac x1)^{n_1}\right)\left(\sum_{n_2=0}^\infty\frac1{n_2!}(\tfrac x2)^{n_2}\right)\left(\sum_{n_3=0}^\infty\frac1{n_3!}(\tfrac x3)^{n_3}\right)...\\
=e^xe^{\tfrac x2}e^{\tfrac x3}...
=e^{x+\tfrac x2+\tfrac x3+...}\\
=e^{\ln(1-x)}=\frac1{1-x}
=1+x+x^2+...$$
Hence $a_n=1$.
(From de Bruijn's combinatorics)
